# Flexdashboard set tabset name based on parameters

Tags: r, flexdashboard

I would like to set a flexdashboard's tabset in R based on parameters. I have a dashboard with a map which is set to create a different based on a parameter. I would like to set the title of the map tab using the parameters.

I tried using title: `r params$parameter1` where the tabset usually goes (### Title), and the output was 'title: parameter1's output', but not formatted like an actual title. Additionally, I would like to be able to set a second line of the title. Currently, I use: ### Hardcoded parameter title Map < br >< span style='font-size:14px'>Hardcoded parameter subtitle< /span > (without spaces) to achieve this but would like the whole title to be parameterized. Thanks